# Git pushes successfully but website doesn't get updated

Tags: git

I'm new on using Git and coding in general and I've recently connected my local files to a remote repository on github through `Git remote add origin <repourl>` and uploaded the changes through:

git add .

git commit -m”something”

git push -u origin master

The changes got successfully pushed to the master branch on the repository and the files get updated but the changes don't show up on the website. Why is this?

Also, there's another branch, gh-pages, which is not updated. Can this be the reason why the website doesn't show up updated? I would also like to know how can I make the changes to commit and push to the two branches?

Repository: 
[image]

Basically, when I open the code on a browser through my local file it appears with the changes that don't show up when I open the website through the repository. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Not enough info. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: "Help others reproduce the problem". Show the repository, the website, explain how the code is published to the website, what exactly doesn't work on pulling.

Comment: I added a few more details, hope that's helpful.

Comment: Still unclear. What is the site? In what way the repository is linked to the site? How do you expect the files from the repository appear at the website?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that command line tools could be a bit confusing to you.

Try https://desktop.github.com/

---

### GitHub Desktop way:

Most likely your website is published with GitHub pages, so you need to update `gh-pages` branch.

Open repository in GitHub Desktop,
Switch to `gh-pages` branch:
[image]

Then go to Branch -> Update from master

[image]

Then click on Push changes.

Your site should be updated in a minute.

### Command line way:

https://github.com/KirstieJane/STEMMRoleModels/wiki/Keeping-gh-pages-up-to-date-with-master

```
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
git commit -m "merged master" -a
git push
```

Comment: thank you, however when I try ```git merge master``` this error comes out ```fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories```. Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: Try checking out master, then `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` for this case, and then check out `gh-pages` and follow the commands.